# Xamarin Forms: WebView loading time is very high

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

I am using `WebView` for loading websites in my project. It is loading websites but very slow. It takes around 10 to 15 seconds to load this [site](https://www.catholicbrain.com/edu-lesson/137414/1/lesson-01-the-purpose-of-man-s-existence-grades-3-5).

I try a solution from this [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/144550/improve-webview-performance). I have added `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` on the manifest under `application` level, but no luck.

For iOS and Windows the solution is below: But I don't know how to create the custom render.

> In iOS, try to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView.
> For the UWP, use Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebViewcontrol instead of using the built-in Xamarin WebView control.

Can I get the sample custom renderer for iOS and Windows-like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is loading websites but very slow

The speed of loading website will up to lots of causes . For example, it will consume a lot of time if the web contains many remote css/js file .  And it will also up to network performance .

The link that you provided loads slow even if on browser on my side . It contains lots of remote css if we check the source code.

For Android , We can create an custom renderer webview to accelerate it.

1. Set Render Priority to hight.
2. Enable the dom storeage.
3. When Loading the html, we can disable the image showing, when
   loading finished, load the image by
   Control.Settings.BlockNetworkImage.
4. Enable the Cache, if you load it at the nexttime, you can load it
   quickly.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(MyWebviewRender))]
namespace MyWebviewDemo.Droid
{
    public class MyWebviewRender : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebviewRender(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
            Control.Settings.CacheMode = Android.Webkit.CacheModes.Normal;
            Control.Settings.SetRenderPriority(RenderPriority.High);
            Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.BlockNetworkImage = true;
            Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        }
    }
    internal class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        public override void OnProgressChanged(Android.Webkit.WebView view, int newProgress)
        {
            base.OnProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            if (newProgress == 100)
            {
                // webview load success

                //  //  loadDialog.dismiss();
                view.Settings.BlockNetworkImage=false;
            }
            else
            {
                //  webview loading
                //  loadDialog.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> In iOS, try to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView. For the UWP, use Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebViewcontrol instead of using the built-in Xamarin WebView control.

In your case it will only have less improve even if using above solution . You could add an  **ActivityIndicator** during the loading . If you can access the website , it would be better to download the css file to local and loading  them in **ContentPage** .

Comment: how we can indicatorview?

Comment: Sorry my mistake , ActivityIndicator .  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/activityindicator

Comment: Initllay the IsRunning value is true for ActivityIndicator. How we can change the status to false? How we can understand the site is loaded on the UI?

Comment: In event FinishLoaded of webview .

Comment: I checked, no such event for webview

Comment: Add `Navigated="xxx"` in WebView in xaml